# Python Tkinter account for lost time

Tags: python, tkinter, elapsedtime, wall-time

I've read similar questions that have been answered:

- [Getting realtime output from ffmpeg to be used in progress bar (PyQt4, stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632589/getting-realtime-output-from-ffmpeg-to-be-used-in-progress-bar-pyqt4-stdout)
- [Progressbar to show amount of music played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789577/progressbar-to-show-amount-of-music-played)
- [How to measure elapsed time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python)

Here's my window:

[image: play progress.gif]

Problem is song ends when counter still has 20% to go. I know the reason is primarily due to system call to check if process is still running `pgrep ffplay` 10 times every second. Secondary reason is simply Python and Tkinter overhead.

To "band-aid fix" the problem I used `1.24` deciseconds instead of `1` every decisecond as my code illustrates now:

```
def play_to_end(self):
    ''' 
    Play single song, checking status every decisecond
    Called from:
        self.play_forever() to start a new song
        self.pp_toggle() to restart song after pausing
    '''
    while True:
        if not self.top2_is_active: return          # Play window closed?
        root.update()                               # Process other events
        if self.pp_state is "Paused": 
            time.sleep(.1)                          # Wait until playing
            continue

        PID = os.popen("pgrep ffplay").read()       # Get PID for ffplay
        if len(PID) < 2:                            # Has song ended?
            return                                  # Song has ended

        #self.current_song_time += .1                # Add decisecond
        self.current_song_time += .124              # Add 1.24 deciseconds
                                                    #  compensatation .24
        self.current_progress.set(str('%.1f' % self.current_song_time) + \
                    " seconds of: " + str(self.DurationSecs))
        root.update()                               # Process other events
        root.after(100)                             # Sleep 1 decisecond
```

The problem with this **band-aid fix** is it is highly machine dependent. My machine is a Skylake for example. Also it is highly dependent on what other processes are running at the same time. When testing my machine load was relatively light:

[image: play progress overhead.gif]

***How can I programmatically account for lost time in order to increment elapsed time accurately?***

Perhaps there is a better way of simply querying `ffplay` to find out song progress?

As an aside (I know it's frowned upon to ask two questions at once) why can't I simply check if `PID` is null? I have tried `.rstrip()` and `.strip()` after `.read()` to no avail with checking `PID` equal to `""` or `None`. If `ffplay` every has a process ID under `10` program will misbehave.

Comment: Have you tried `.after()` in tkinter?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Yes the original design was using `.after()` referencing all kinds of frames and labels, etc. I gave up and went with `root.after` which always seemed to work and is in the last line of code. That doesn't help the time compensation though...

Comment: How do you start the `ffplay`? Using `subprocess.Popen()`?

Comment: @acw1668 The first line is `os.popen('ffplay -autoexit ' + '"' + self.current_song_path + '"'`  continued on the second line: ``+ ' -nodisp 2>' + TMP_CURR_SONG + ' &')``

Comment: Try using `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.popen()` and redirect the `stderr` to PIPE, then you can read the `stderr` to update the progress.

Comment: @acw1668 That is a great solution for this particular use case. In general though someone without `ffplay` may want to know progress to total time. Accounting for system overhead would be needed in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subprocess.Popen()` to execute `ffplay` and redirect `stderr` to PIPE, then you can read the progress from `stderr` and update the progress label.

Below is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as subp
import threading

class MediaPlayer(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        self.proc = None
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quit)

    def init_ui(self):
        self.current_progress = tk.StringVar()
        self.progress = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.current_progress)
        self.progress.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        btn_close = tk.Button(self, text='Stop', width=20, command=self.stop_playing)
        btn_close.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

        btn_play = tk.Button(self, text='Play', width=20, command=self.play_song)
        btn_play.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')

    def play_to_end(self):
        self.proc = subp.Popen(
            ['ffplay', '-nodisp', '-hide_banner', '-autoexit', self.current_song_path],
            stderr=subp.PIPE, bufsize=1, text=1
        )
        duration = ''
        while self.proc.poll() is None:
            msg = self.proc.stderr.readline().strip()
            if msg:
                if msg.startswith('Duration'):
                    duration = msg.split(',')[0].split(': ')[1]
                else:
                    msg = msg.split()[0]
                    if '.' in msg:
                        elapsed = float(msg)
                        mins, secs = divmod(elapsed, 60)
                        hrs, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
                        self.current_progress.set('Play Progress: {:02d}:{:02d}:{:04.1f} / {}'.format(int(hrs), int(mins), secs, duration))
        print('done')
        self.proc = None

    def play_song(self):
        self.current_song_path = '/path/to/song.mp3'
        if self.proc is None:
            threading.Thread(target=self.play_to_end, daemon=True).start()

    def stop_playing(self):
        if self.proc:
            self.proc.terminate()

    def quit(self):
        self.stop_playing()
        self.destroy()

app = MediaPlayer()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Did you have some/most of this code written previously?

Comment: I have similar answer to another question in SO.